# Exception while invoking method 'myMethod' Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code puts out this error: 
Any idea how and where to start looking? 
The code uses ddp to make calls to other apps and receives calls from other apps.

```
Exception while invoking method 'myMethod' Error: read ECONNRESET
    at Object.Future.wait (/opt/bundle/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
    at Object.call (packages/meteor.js:213:24)
    at Object.HTTP.get (meteor://app/packages/http/httpcall_common.js:50:20)
    at Object.freeze.CFDescription (meteor://app/server/lib.js:502:24)
    at null.Meteor.methods.otherDescriptions (meteor://app/server/methods.js:151:9)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (meteor://app/packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1737:12)
    at meteor://app/packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:719:19
    at null._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1122:17)
    at meteor://app/packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:717:40
    at null._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1122:17)
    - - - - -
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:911:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:558:26)
```

Here is what the method looks like:

```js
    'myMethod': (w) => { //6a
      let url = 'https://www.some-url.com/Search/Result?vin=' + w + '&IdentificationType=name';
      const res = HTTP.get(url);
      const ResObj = {$: cheerio.load(res.content), html: res.content};
      let doc = myCol.findOne({name: w});
      const elms = ResObj.$('.panel-body');
      const elemLine = ResObj.$('.panel-body').text().replace(/\s*?(^|\n)\s*/g, '$1').split('\n'); //each 4 lines for one description


        myCol.update({vin: vin}, {$set: {a: aa, b: bb}}, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            lib.printDebugInfo('done');
          }
        });
      }
    },
```

Comment: Share your method code please.

Comment: simplified version has been posted. please post. thx

Comment: Maybe due the simplification you made, there are some vars not defined in your code and others are never used. I understand sometimes is difficult to isolate code and keep it consistent. Said that, what I can suggest you is to debug your server code. If you don't have an specific tool to do that you can add a `console.log` each other line inside `myMethod` and check which one is the last printed to identify the line generating the error.  But before that,  check if `get`  is getting a valid `url` after pasting `w`.